# Get ID from Photo when saving

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

In my application, I catch a photo and save it on the mobile phone then.

This is how I do that:

```
private void takePic() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String TITLE = null;
    values.put(MediaColumns.TITLE, TITLE);
    String DESCRIPTION  = null;
    values.put(ImageColumns.DESCRIPTION, DESCRIPTION);
    values.put(MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

My problem now is, that I later want to get the thumbnail of this picture to show the thumbnail in my ListView. Is there a way to get the id of the photo I took and save it to my `Intent` or something like this?

Comment: Nobody here that knows an answer?

Comment: you can get Media ID by querying `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` for `MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID` in `onActivityResult` when image successfully stored in Content Provider

Comment: thank you. Do you have any code example how that works? Never worked with that..

Answer (score 3):

you can try it as by quering `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` for Media Uri which you have instead in MediaStore Content Provider

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK ){
          if(requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE){
                  // get Media Uri from data

                  Uri media_uri = data.getData();
                  String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};

                  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(media_uri, column, 
                                                               null, null, null);
                  cursor.moveToFirst();
                  if(cursor.getCount()>0){
                    int Media_ID = cursor.getInt(cursor  
                             .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID)); 
                    //... store media ID here..
                  }
                 cursor.close();
           }
        }
    }
```